# MySQL bitwise AND 256-bit binary values

Tags: mysql, blob, bit-manipulation

I'm intending on storing a 256-bit long binary value in a MySQL table column.

Which column type should I be using (blob?) such that I can run bitwise operations against it (example of an AND would be ideal).

Comment: 256-bit is only 32 byte. Not really a *Binary Large OBject*. Do you only have to *store* those values on the DB. Or do you plan to perform some operations on them (search by value, pattern matching, arithmetic operations, bit-wise logic operations)...

Comment: I'm planning on using bit-wise operations on them.

Comment: OK, only bit-wise operation. As this is an interesting question I've done some experiments. Could you confirm that this expression from your answer below `bin(label & b'01..00')` works as expected if `label` is a `BLOB` column? For me, it doesn't work ?!? Always returning `0`...

Comment: It does work in the select although I couldn't seem to make it work for the where clause and I haven't checked with >64-bits yet.

Comment: I think this *might* work up to 64 bits. But certainly not above. I've edited my answer below to what I think to be the only decently working solution: split your 256-bit value as 4 64-bit `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. Not excessively elegant, but that works, and you will have access to the "full power" of the MySQL bit-wise operators as well as to the various conversion function (`HEX()`, `BIN()`).

Comment: To come back to the `BLOB`, I confirm this does not work with MySQL5.1: having a table with a `BLOB` column, `insert into t values (b'11110000');` then `select hex(b) from t;` gives `F0`, which is correct. But `select bin(b) from t;` produce `0` which is obviously wrong. The reason is `BIN()` only works with numbers. Whereas `HEX` accept both numbers *or* strings... Bitwise operators don't work for me neither on BLOB: `select hex(b & b'01111111') from t;` produces `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you could find some way to perform bit-wise operation on 256-bit values at SQL level as the doc clearly state that:

> MySQL uses BIGINT (64-bit) arithmetic for bit operations, so these operators have a maximum range of 64 bits.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and

---

As for *storing* those values, `TINYBLOB` is possible, but my personal *preference* would go to simply `BINARY(32)` (a *binary string* of 32 bytes -- 256-bits).

---

---

While writing this, one *trick* came to my mind. If we are limited to 64-bit values (`BIGINT UNSIGNED`), why not store your 256-bit as 4 words of 64-bits. Not very elegant but that would work. Especially here since you only need bitwise operations:

ABCD<sub>32</sub> & WXYZ<sub>32</sub> == A<sub>8</sub> & W<sub>8</sub>, B<sub>8</sub> & X<sub>8</sub>, C<sub>8</sub> & Y<sub>8</sub>, D<sub>8</sub> & Z<sub>8</sub>

Very basically:

```
create table t (a bigint unsigned, 
                b bigint unsigned, 
                c bigint unsigned, 
                d bigint unsigned);
```

While inserting, 256-bit values has to be "split" on 4 words:

```
-- Here I use hexadecimal notation for conciseness. you may use b'010....000' if you want 
insert into t values (0xFFFFFFFF,
                      0xFFFF0000,
                      0xFF00FF00,
                      0xF0F0F0F0);
```

You could easily query the 256-bit value:

```
mysql> select CONCAT(LPAD(HEX(a),8,'0'),
                     LPAD(HEX(b),8,'0'),
                     LPAD(HEX(c),8,'0'),
                     LPAD(HEX(d),8,'0')) from t;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(LPAD(HEX(a),8,'0'),
                     LPAD(HEX(b),8,'0'),
                     LPAD(HEX(c),8,'0'),
                     LPAD(HEX(d),8,'0')) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FFFFFFFFFFFF0000FF00FF00F0F0F0F0                                                                                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I used hexadecimal here again, but you could display as binary by replacing ̀`HEX()` by `BIN()`

And last but not least you could perform binary operation on them. Once again, you just have to "split" the operand. Assuming I want to apply the 256 bits mask `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000000` to all values in the table:

```
update t set a = a & 0xFFFFFFFF, 
             b = b & 0xFFFFFFFF, 
             c = c & 0x00000000, 
             d = d & 0x00000000;
```

Comment: +1 Until MySQL implements the Oracle style `RAW` datatype, or implements the 256-bit unsigned `REALLYBIGINT UNSIGNED` datatype, an integer type is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like blob works with a query like this for the bitwise and:

```
select id,bin(label & b'01000000010000001000000000000000000') from projects;
```